# How to send a confirm email from swift

Tags: swift, uikit

In my app I've a button that allows users to send me an e-mail.
When users send me an e-mail I want to send to their a confirm e-mail.
But, from swift code, how can I get their email address in order to send to their the confirm mail?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to use Swift to grab a user's email address this way. This is intentional, to keep a user's information secure.

I would recommended either using an email service that will automatically respond to emails received, or allowing users to enter their email address elsewhere in the app.